# not able to change div content on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Well, all i am doing right now is trying to use a simple code from this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/unbornink/LUKGt/ to change the div content on click of links just to check if it works with my website.But it doesnt.It shows all the three divs all the time,no matter which link is clicked

```
   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<style>
    .linkdetails {
        width: 180px;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .detailscontainer {
        width: 220px;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        background-color: #111;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        border-right: #222 1px solid;
        color: #FFF;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.linkdetails').hide();

    $('.link').click(function () {
        $('.linkdetails').hide();
        $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
            width: '200px'
        }, 300);
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

<a class="link" data-link="first" href="#">link 1</a>
<a class="link" data-link="second" href="#">link 2</a>
<a class="link" data-link="third" href="#">link 3</a>

<div class="detailscontainer">
    <div class="linkdetails" data-link="first">content 1</div>
    <div class="linkdetails" data-link="second">content 2</div>
    <div class="linkdetails" data-link="third">content 3</div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Is it because of my masterpage? Or what am i doing wrong? Works just fine in the above fiddle.

Comment: issue is you are trying to hide the divs using jquery before they are loaded into DOM, write JQuery  code inside `document.ready`  or just write the script content after the divs

Comment: It works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was about to say same thing as @J Santosh, the tag is not ready when the script is executed. Make sure you add document ready in the script like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.linkdetails').hide();

    $('.link').click(function () {
        $('.linkdetails').hide();
        $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
            width: '200px'
        }, 300);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

insert your jQuery code inside :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //here
});
```

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.linkdetails').hide();

    $('.link').click(function () {
    $('.linkdetails').hide();
    $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what @Jackie described. Execution is done in a single pass. If you are accessing the DOM from Javascript you have to make sure that your code runs after the browser has added the relevant DOM elements.

This is just my opinion but I try to avoid using $(document).ready. Instead I add my Javascript code at the bottom. Using document.ready adds an extra delay which most of the time it's not worth.

Your Html/Javascript code would look like this:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

  <a class="link" data-link="first" href="#">link 1</a>
  <a class="link" data-link="second" href="#">link 2</a>
  <a class="link" data-link="third" href="#">link 3</a>

  <div class="detailscontainer">
    <div class="linkdetails" data-link="first">content 1</div>
    <div class="linkdetails" data-link="second">content 2</div>
    <div class="linkdetails" data-link="third">content 3</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.linkdetails').hide();

    $('.link').click(function() {
      $('.linkdetails').hide();
      $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
      }, 300);
    });
  </script>

</asp:Content>
```